# Active areas of research for NISQ algorithms

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, research, nisq, vqe

What areas of research in NISQ algorithms have heavy focus? I'm interested in quantum chemistry algorithms because of previous work (e.g. VQEs), and I'd love to learn more about other near-term algorithms that are being explored.

Comment: Subscribe to the USRA NISQ computing newsletter (arxiv digest) to be posted on most recent research on the topic: https://riacs.usra.edu/quantum/nisqc-nl (one email a month).
Disclaimer: I am an editor of the arxiv digest.